# Android MediaPlayer error (1, -38) on Android 2.3 devices

Tags: android

Recently be assigned a task to develop an Android app to play RTSP streams via WiFI. The app is utilizing Android MediaPlayer class on SurfaceView, same code works on Android 4.2, 4.3 and 4.4, however, when try it on 2.3, it suffers Android MediaPlayer error (1, -38) after calling MediaPlayer.start() function.

After brainstorming for a couple of days, I found the answer and would like to share to save people's time as there is very limited information related to this problem on line(Probably I didn't search hard enough :)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just for answering my own question to share the findings.

To solve the problem of MediaPlayer error (1,-38) after calling mediaPlayer.start() on Android 2.3 device, just add the following clause after setting up the surface holder.

`...;
    surfaceHolder_.addCallback(this);
    surfaceHolder_.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    mediaPlayer_ = new MediaPlayer();
    ...;`

For devices equal to or higher than Honeycomb, we don't need to set the surface holder type, the framework will handle that automatically for the attached surface view to the media player, that's why the code works in Android 4.0 but not in 2.3. Hence we can use a condition statement to guard the surface holder setType clause as:

`if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        surfaceHolder_.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }`

Comment: do you have any suggestion about on error(1,-38) ? what does -38 mean ?