# Play video using surfaceview in android getting error as E/MediaPlayer﹕ Error (1,-38)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-mediaplayer, surfaceview

Hi I want to play a media(video) file on surfaceview, so I am trying in follwing way.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myProject" >
    <permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/surfView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Then I have created a /raw folder under /res folder and added a video(newmovie.mp4) in it.

Now In **MainActivity** I am trying to play that video in this way.

```
package com.example.myProject;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;

import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback,OnPreparedListener{

    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    private SurfaceHolder vidHolder;
    private SurfaceView vidSurface;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        vidSurface = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfView);
        vidHolder = vidSurface.getHolder();
        vidHolder.addCallback(this);
        vidHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
       }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container,
                    false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        mediaPlayer.start();

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        try {

            String fileName = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.newmovie;
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(this, Uri.parse(fileName));

            mediaPlayer.setDisplay(vidHolder);

            mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
            mediaPlayer.prepare();



        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
                               int height) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

But I am getting error as 'E/MediaPlayer﹕ Error (1,-38)' after running this application as a result getting blank screen.

Also getting error as 'E/MediaPlayer﹕ Should have subtitle controller already set' which can be neglected as it will not stop to play video file.

When I tried to debug and see the file-name at run-time is like "*android.resource://com.example.myProject/21348349*", but my video resides in res/raw/ folder. How android gets my video at run-time ?

Can anyone guide me for this what is the meaning of this error and how can I resolve it.

Comment: is this error coming due to wrong media path,I have tried to search but didn't get perfect way to play video from raw folder.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android MediaPlayer error (1, -38) on Android 2.3 devices](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25276459/android-mediaplayer-error-1-38-on-android-2-3-devices)